# Three JS: Rotate Object on its axis using trackball control

Tags: animation, three.js, 3d

Here I'm trying to rotate object on its axis using trackball ball by rotating the camera not the object. I have used the theory of quaternion in three JS by rotating the object where I need to rotate the object on its axis with the help of the camera in trackball Control. Heres the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xvzh7yqk/

```
   initScene = function() {

  var canvasWidth   = 500;
  var canvasHeight  = 500;
  var scene3d;
  init();
  animate();

  // init scene
  function init(){

    //new THREE.Scene
    scene3d = new THREE.Scene();

    //set the scene
    var canvas3d = $( '#canvas3d' );

    //new THREE.WebGLRenderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: canvas3d.get( 0 ), antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( canvasWidth, canvasHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor( 0x121224, 1 );

    //new THREE.PerspectiveCamera
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, canvasWidth / canvasHeight, 0.1, 10000 );
    camera.name = 'camera';
    scene3d.add( camera );

    // TEST =============
    var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 2, 2 );
    var mat  = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geom, mat );
    var pos = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0 ,0 );
    cube.position.set( pos.x, pos.y, pos.z );
    scene3d.add(cube);
    camera.position.set( pos.x, pos.y, pos.z+20 );
    camera.lookAt(pos);

    // new THREE.TrackballControls
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.5;
    controls.target.set( pos.x, pos.y, pos.z );

    //new THREE.AmbientLight (soft white light)
    var light   = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 );
    light.name  = 'ambientLight';
    scene3d.add( light );
    //new THREE.PointLight ( white light )
    var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8, 0 );
    camera.add( pointLight );
    render();
  }
  function animate() {
    requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();
    render();
  }
  function render() {
    var camera = scene3d.getObjectByName( 'camera' );
    renderer.render( scene3d, camera );
  }
};

initScene();
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate a 3D object on axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56024223/how-to-rotate-a-3d-object-on-axis)

Comment: How to rotate a object on its axis when panned in trackball control @meowgoesthedog

Comment: Nope. I just disabled the trackball functionalities and used quaternion for rotate @2pha

Comment: No it is, It rotates the object not the camera. I'm trying to rotate the camera @TomaszZieliński

Comment: I suggest that you make your intentions clearer on your original post, as it's not clear what you meant. Now that you cleared a few points. I believe that you can achieve the intended behavior by binding trackball to a second camera, copying the rotation from that camera to your object at every frame, but use a fixed camera to render the scene. If this is not clear I can write an answer detailing the process.

Comment: Also, my solution might work better with an `OrbitControl`, instead of a `TrackballControl`.

Comment: @ScieCode Thanks! you got my point
Can you share some sample using orbitControl which it can be achieved